# JSON <NonSerialized()> not working VB.NET?

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, casting

I'm having a bit of trouble with some JSON serialization that I'm doing in VB.NET.

Basically, I have two classes.

*MenuItemDataLong*
And *MenuItemDataShort*

*MenuItemDataLong* inherits *MenuItemDataShort*.

Code:

**MenuItemDataShort.vb**

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class MenuItemDataShort
    Public Display_Name As String = ""
    Public Display_Description As String = ""
    Public Display_Price As Single = 0.0

    Public SELECTED_NAME As Integer = 0
    Public SELECTED_PRICE As Integer = 0

    Public WEB_IMAGE As String = ""
    Public WEB_IMAGE_WIDTH As Integer = 0
    Public WEB_IMAGE_HEIGHT As Integer = 0

    Public PAGE_NUM As Integer = 0
    Public CELL_ID As Integer = 0

    Public SHOW_BMP_FILE As Boolean = False
    Public SHOW_DESCRIPT As Boolean = False
    Public SHOW_PRICE As Boolean = False
    Public SHOW_LONG_DESC As Boolean = False

    Public LONG_DESC_FONT_NAME As String
    Public LONG_DESC_FONT_BOLD As Boolean
    Public LONG_DESC_FONT_UNDERLINE As Boolean
    Public LONG_DESC_FONT_ITALIC As Boolean
    Public LONG_DESC_FONT_COLOR_R As Integer
    Public LONG_DESC_FONT_COLOR_G As Integer
    Public LONG_DESC_FONT_COLOR_B As Integer
    Public LONG_DESC_FONT_SIZE As Integer

    Public DESC_FONT_NAME As String
    Public DESC_FONT_BOLD As Boolean
    Public DESC_FONT_UNDERLINE As Boolean
    Public DESC_FONT_ITALIC As Boolean
    Public DESC_FONT_COLOR_R As Integer
    Public DESC_FONT_COLOR_G As Integer
    Public DESC_FONT_COLOR_B As Integer
    Public DESC_FONT_SIZE As Integer

    Public PRICE_FONT_NAME As String
    Public PRICE_FONT_BOLD As Boolean
    Public PRICE_FONT_UNDERLINE As Boolean
    Public PRICE_FONT_ITALIC As Boolean
    Public PRICE_FONT_COLOR_R As Integer
    Public PRICE_FONT_COLOR_G As Integer
    Public PRICE_FONT_COLOR_B As Integer
    Public PRICE_FONT_SIZE As Integer

    Public DESC_X As Integer
    Public DESC_Y As Integer
    Public PRICE_X As Integer
    Public PRICE_Y As Integer
    Public IMAGE_X As Integer
    Public IMAGE_Y As Integer
    Public LONG_DESC_X As Integer
    Public LONG_DESC_Y As Integer
End Class
```

**MenuItemDataLong.vb**

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class MenuItemDataLong
    Inherits MenuItemDataShort

    <NonSerialized()>
    Public DESCRIPT As String

    <NonSerialized()>
    Public OO_Alias As String

    <NonSerialized()>
    Public LONG_DESCRIPTION As String

    <NonSerialized()>
    Public RECIPE_DESCRIPTION As String

    <NonSerialized()>
    Public BMP_FILE As String

    <NonSerialized()>
    Public PRICE1, PRICE2, PRICE3, PRICE4, PRICE5, PRICE6, PRICE7, PRICE8, PRICE9, PRICE10, PRICE11, PRICE12, PRICE13, PRICE14 As Single

End Class
```

I then have the *MenuItemDataLong* object stored somewhere. The excess data in the *MenuItemDataLong* class is necessary in application, but is not necessary once the file is serialized. So, I'm trying to take the *MenuItemDataLong* and cast it back down to a *MenuItemDataShort* and serialize it. However, Whenever I do I end up with all of the data from *MenuItemDataLong* still in it, even with the *NonSerialized()* tags.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?..

EDIT:
If anyone is curious, this is how I'm serializing:

```
Dim sItemData As MenuItemDataShort = CType(ItemData, MenuItemDataShort)
Dim Serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
Dim Serialized As String = Serializer.Serialize(sItemData)
```

Comment: From MSDN for `NonSerialized`: *When using the BinaryFormatter or SoapFormatter classes to serialize an object, use the NonSerializedAttribute attribute to prevent a field from being serialized.*  It doesnt mention the XMLSerializer or JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: @Plutonix, I read somewhere that it should work with the JSON serialization as well. However, if that is not the case what would I used to make the properties NonSerialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically using the wrong attribute.  From [MSDN - NonSerialized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When using the BinaryFormatter or SoapFormatter classes to serialize an object, use the NonSerializedAttribute attribute to prevent a field from being serialized.

It does not mention the `JavaScriptSerializer`.  There is another attribute: `<ScriptIgnore>` which seems to work.  Using simplified classes and a mix of  actual Properties and Fields:

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

<Serializable()>
Public Class MenuItemShort   
    Public Property Name As String = ""
    Public Description As String = ""
End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class MenuItemLong
    Inherits MenuItemShort

    <ScriptIgnore>
    Public Property Foo As String
    <ScriptIgnore>
    Public Bar As String

    Public Property Value As Integer
End Class
```

Test Code:

```
Dim mi As New MenuItemLong With {.Name = "foo",
                                 .Description = "a foo item",
                                 .Foo = "ghost in the machine",
                                 .Bar = "bar",
                                 .Value = 42}

Dim miS As MenuItemShort = DirectCast(mi, MenuItemShort)

Dim jser As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
Dim jss As String = jser.Serialize(miS)

Console.WriteLine(jss)
```

Output:

> {"Description":"a foo item","Value":42,"Name":"foo"}

There are other ways to ignore certain properties using NewtonSoft's JSON.Net.

Comment: glad to help.  It is actually more powerful than `NonSerialized` because it can be used with properties *or* fields